# Featured images of shared links disappeared from FaceBook

Tags: facebook

### The images of links shared from my website disappeared from my FaceBook business page.

**I have a WordPress blog.**
For about a year, there was no problem: if I shared a link from my website on FaceBook, the featured image was displayed.

**A month ago, two problems arose:**

1. Most of the images of links shared from my website disappeared from
   one moment to another.
2. If I shared a new link from my website, the
   image was displayed, but as soon as I posted something again, the
   image belonging to the previous post disappeared.

I asked help from a developer (I am not skilled in programming), who fixed the problem for the future, so hopefully links I share in the future won't be affected by this problem. However: **I  still have 50 older posts the featured image of which are not diplayed.** 
This is my FaceBook Page: https://www.facebook.com/izekmentesen/ Please scroll down to see there is no image displayed for older posts.

This is a recipe blog, so older posts are just as important as new ones, they will not loose their relevance. 
Could anyone help me fix this issue?

**I already tried these:**

1. I tried to deactivate all plugins one by one. After each deactivation, I refreshed the cache of my website, re-fetched one of the affected links with FaceBook Object Debugger and checked if the image was diplayed on my FaceBook page. Nothing happened.
2. I tried to change the image (then refreshed the cache of my website, and re-fetched the link of the post with Object Debugger). This did not solve the problem either.
3. I set my Open Graph plugin to use the first image in the post as an og:image. (By default, it would use the featured image.) No success.

**Whenever I make Object Debugger fetch a link from my website, I got this warning:**

Extraneous Property: Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'og:site_name'.
The same warning is given concerning to: 'og:title',  'og:url', 'og:type',
'og:description','og:image','og:image:url', 'og:image:secure_url','og:image:width', 'og:image:height', 'article:publisher' and 'fb:app_id'.

**I would really appreciate if someone could help me.**

Comment: For `https://izekmentesen.hu/alapanyagok-glutenmentes-etrendhez/` f.e. the debugger shows everything to be okay now, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fizekmentesen.hu%2Falapanyagok-glutenmentes-etrendhez%2F - so it should work, if you share that link again. For the already existing posts on Facebook, you will probably have to refresh the share attachment via the post context menu manually now.

Comment: Thank you for you comment! Sharing Debugger shows no problem, but unfortunately, the Object Debugger does: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/  . FaceBook does not allow to change the image of shared links, only to modify the text.

Comment: But https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fizekmentesen.hu%2Falapanyagok-glutenmentes-etrendhez%2F already shows that it is using an og:image? Is https://izekmentesen.hu/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/alapanyagok_glutenmentes_etrendhez-1.jpg not the image you want for that particular article …?

Comment: The image shown by the Debugger is the image I want for the article. I posted this article on my FaceBook page a few weeks ago, but the image is not displayed. If I check my post on FaceBook, I only see a grey box instead of the image.

Comment: As I said, if the images were broken at the time you posted those links, then you will have to manually refresh the share attachment for those posts for them to update, that doesn’t happen automatically.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did't know how to refresh the share attachment, but with  help I could do it, and all images are displayed again. Thank you again, I really appreciate your help!